# How to show navigation bar back

Tags: ios, xcode, gridview, uiview, navigationbar

How to write a **CODE** to show the navigationBar back in grid view of UIView after clicked navigationBar right item button to hidden?  My design is, when tap the grid view, it will show its big picture.  My project write codes and don't use storyboard.    Thank you for reply!

I wish I could post the image to describe it, and make it easy to understand.
However, I am new here.

Tks! There are two parts of codes...

```
//part-1 code:
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=NSLocalizedString(@"showPhoto", nil);
    MainViewController *mainController=[self revealViewController];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:mainController.panGestureRecognizer];

    //leftBarButtonItem
    UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:      [UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"]                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:mainController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;

    //rightButton ------
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]                                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showHideNavbar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem;
}

    -(void) showHideNavbar:(id) sender{
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}


//part-2 code:

//tapGestureDetected:
    -(void)tapGestureDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    //??????xxxxxxx
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        // hide the Navigation Bar
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
    {
        // Show the Navigation Bar
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    }//??????xxxxxxx

    if(_lastTouchedPosition.row >= 0 && _lastTouchedPosition.column >= 0)
    {
        [_easeThread cancel];
        _easeThread = nil;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^
         {
             [self reloadData];
         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             _lastTouchedPosition = DWPositionMake(-55, -55);
         }];
    }

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gridView:didSelectCell:atPosition:)])
    {
        DWPosition touchPosition = [self determinePositionAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:self]];

        if(touchPosition.row != _lastTouchedPosition.row && touchPosition.column != _lastTouchedPosition.column)
        {
            DWGridViewCell *cell = [self.delegate gridView:self cellAtPosition:touchPosition];
            [self.delegate gridView:self didSelectCell:cell atPosition:touchPosition];

        }
    }
}


//didSelectCell
-(void)gridView:(DWGridView *)gridView didSelectCell:(DWGridViewCell *)cell atPosition:(DWPosition)position
    {
    NSDictionary *cellDictionary = [self cellDictionaryAtPosition:position];
    UIImage *image = [cellDictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UIViewController *contr = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [contr.view addSubview:button];

    [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
    [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];

    [self presentViewController:contr animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please add your code for when tapping on a grid item. Thanks

Comment: Tks, Rich!  I pasted it up on the top.

Comment: Can you also paste the code for your delegate implementation of `-gridView:didSelectCell:atPosition:`. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you push the `UIViewController *contr` on to the `self.navigationController`? Or do you want the modal popover effect?

Comment: I designed splitView, and there are different effects in every modal.  Therefore, The navi. is controlled in main view controller.  Indeed, I can pin the grid view under navBar, and make navBar was not be hidden.  How can I paste the image to make it clear?  tks once more~

Comment: Just out of interest what is `UIButton *button` (the one that gets added to `contr.view`)? Do you also want to dismiss when this button is pressed or only the right nav bar button?

Comment: May I have your mail and send the images to u?

Comment: Its ok, I'll give the option of pressing the button dismissing the popover

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the view controller to a navigation controller and then present this modally. To add a right nav button you set this on the [`rightBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItem) of the view controller's [`navigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem). To dismiss it you then need to add a target to the [`UIBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) just like you would a `UIButton`.

As you've currently constrained `button` to fill the whole view controller, when adding a navigation bar this will most likely not work - it will show under the navigation bar. To get around this, the top vertical constraint needs to be against the `topGuide` (this is called [`topLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide) in code, but `topGuide` in visual format language) instead of the view controllers `view`.

```
//didSelectCell
-(void)gridView:(DWGridView *)gridView didSelectCell:(DWGridViewCell *)cell atPosition:(DWPosition)position
    {
    NSDictionary *cellDictionary = [self cellDictionaryAtPosition:position];
    UIImage *image = [cellDictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UIViewController *contr = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    contr.navigationItem.rigthBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(didTapToDismissBigPicture)];
    [contr.view addSubview:button];

    [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
    [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topGuide]-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contr];

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Button target
-(void)didTapToDismissBigPicture
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

If you also want to dismiss the modal popover when you tap on the picture add another target to `button` pointing to the `didTapToDismissBigPicture`, I haven't shown that as you already have a target on the button, so I don't know what you're doing with that